# Is it possible to expose boot2docker ip on local wifi

Tags: docker, virtualbox, boot2docker

Boot2docker as we know runs on a virtuelbox.

I would like to access boot2docker from my phone on local wifi, just for testing. Is is possible to expose boot2docker so you can access the "boot2docker ip"?

Comment: You can't expose the IP, but you can expose ports on the host boot2docker is running on, and forward those ports to the VM.  You'll then, in  theory, be able  to use any docker client to talk to the docker service.

Answer (score 0):

You need to port forward the ports you want in the VirtualBox Manager.  Run it, select Settings.  Network.  Port Forwarding.  Manually add your ports.  Or, do it with this:

```
$ sudo /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxManage controlvm \
       boot2docker-vm natpf1 "tcp-port10035,tcp,,10035,,10035"
```

which forward port 10035, for example.